# c# how to add resize button squares?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, resize, mouseevent

Hi i want to make a square to resize button like from normal button to this: https://prnt.sc/ESy2d63JMgRv if you know how to do resizing squares to resize top, left, right and bottom of button by dragging mouse please let me know

Comment: Like, when your application is running you want to resize button? Or in the designer?

Comment: no see the first link and you see what is going on

Answer (score 1):

I could not fully understand whether you want to make such a change while the application is running or in the designer, neither the link you shared above nor the question is fully explanatory, but I tried to write something about how this can be done while the application is running.

I'm writing this to give you some idea of ​​how to do it, obviously the code below doesn't solve your specific problem.

```
        private int squareSize = 5;
        private bool isDragging = false;
        private bool onlyX = false;
        private bool onlyY = false;
        private bool bothXY = false;
```

You need to draw squares on the corners and edges of the button.

```
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Left - squareSize, button1.Top - squareSize), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Right - (button1.Right - button1.Left) / 2, button1.Top - squareSize), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));
            Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Right, button1.Top), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));
            Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Left - squareSize, button1.Bottom - (button1.Bottom - button1.Top) / 2), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));
            Rectangle rect5 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Right, button1.Bottom - (button1.Bottom - button1.Top) / 2), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));
            Rectangle rect6 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Left - squareSize, button1.Bottom - squareSize), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));
            Rectangle rect7 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Left + (button1.Right - button1.Left) / 2, button1.Bottom), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));
            Rectangle rect8 = new Rectangle(new Point(button1.Right, button1.Bottom - squareSize), new Size(squareSize, squareSize));

            // copy the left, right, top and bottom coordinates of the rectangles above.
            // draw the rectangles.
        }
```

You need to write the mouse down event to determine which corner or edge it was grabbed and dragged
(For example, the first and eighth squares act on the x=-y line, while the third and sixth squares act on the x=y line, with that in mind I suggest you write different boolean values so you can differentiate when resizing the button.), something like this:

```
 private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Dragging first rectangle, changes on both axis
            if (e.Location.X < rect1Right && e.Location.X > rect1Left && e.Location.Y < rect1Bottom && e.Location.Y > rect1Top && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                bothXY = true;
                isDragging = true;
            }
            // Dragging second rectangle, changes on only y-axis
            if (e.Location.X < rect2Right && e.Location.X > rect2Left && e.Location.Y < rect2Bottom && e.Location.Y > rect2Top && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                onlyY = true;
                isDragging = true;
            }
        }
```

You should write a mouse move event function to determine the direction and amount of movement on each axis. (I'm not sure if you should do the resizing inside that function, give it a try.)

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDragging && bothXY)
            {
                resizeX = e.X - button1.Right;
                resizeY = e.Y - button1.Bottom;
            }
            if(isDragging && onlyY)
            {
                resizeY = e.Y - button1.Bottom;
            }

            button1.Width += resizeX;
            button1.Height += resizeY;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
```

And finally you should write a mouse up  event where you reset all boolean values to initials to stop resizing the button.

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            onlyY = false;
            onlyX = false;
            bothXY = false;
        }
```